# Из трех колонок в две в Bootstrap при media screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Привет! Кто-нибудь подскажет как мне три столбика преобразовать в два при изменении разрешения экрана. Используется `Bootstrap`. При достижении экрана в `1200px` все столбики сразу переходят в одну колонку. То есть нужно по идее изменить в `HTML` `col-md-4` в `col-md-6`, но как ?)

Comment: Вопрос просто некорректный, никаких условий нет.

Answer (score 1):

В бустрапе при достижении ширины 1200px используются классы `col-lg-`
[Bootstrap grid-options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

Скрыть третью колонку можно добавив класс `hidden-lg`. Больше информации о классах скрытия колонок [responsive-utilities-classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes).

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-6">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-6">2</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 hidden-lg">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: В бутстрапе [уже предусмотрены классы](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes), чтобы показывать или прятать контент в зависимости от ширины экрана. Например, `.hidden-lg`.